# rotating an image with smooth speed

Tags: objective-c

Using this code I'm trying to rotate an image. Image rotated but with a same speed.
I'm trying to rotate an image with smooth rotation but I can't do this. Here is my code:

```
(void)spinLayer:(CALayer *)inLayer duration:(CFTimeInterval)inDuration
    direction:(int)direction repeat:(int)repeat
{
    repeatcount = repeat+repeatcount;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: inDuration target: self     selector:@selector(setCountLableValue) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation =
    [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI *2.0 * direction];
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;
    NSLog(@"Repeat count %d",repeat);
    rotationAnimation.duration = inDuration;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [inLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotation"];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different timingFunctions you can use. You used a linear function, try one of these instead of `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear`

```
NSString * const kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn;
NSString * const kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut;
NSString * const kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut;
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Regarding the repeating problem, try adding the following code after creating the animation: (this is just an idea, I really don't know why the ease function is only used once)

```
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompleted = NO;
rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
```

Comment: What happens after the first rotation? Does it stop or continue without the ease function?

Comment: it continues but without effect